# New AssociationThread forms in 10.2?

Tags: bugs, syntax, documentation

**Bug introduced in 10.2.0 and fixed in 10.3.0**

***(The extension of `AssociationThread` is not (yet) implemented and the corresponding documentation has been removed)***

---

Is this another case of **"documented"** but **"not implemented"** ? or at least it is not explained clearly as I cannot make it work:

Two new forms appears in the new [10.2 doc.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html) of `AssociationThread` (the last two ones below):

[image]

which forms, for comparison, are not present in [10.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10/ref/AssociationThread.html) or [10.1](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.1/ref/AssociationThread.html) docs. However, there is no "updated" sign anywhere (no "UPDATE (show changes)" icon and the page footer only mentions "introduced in 2014 (10.0)".

Also, the new templates forms can be accessed through the "Make Template" menu/shortcut:

[image]

But I didn't manage to get the new forms to work at all, I only get error messages strongly indicating that these forms have actually not been implemented.

For example:

**New form 1**

```
AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 2]
AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"}, whateverYouPutHere, orHere]
```

returns

[image]

**New form 2**

```
AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"}][{1, 2, 3}]
AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C"}]@{1, 2, 3}
```

returns

[image]

Comment: I would report to support@wolfram.com as a bug.  Either the docs or the function is wrong.

Comment: So we will get a non-beta-version 10.2.1 soon?

Comment: It's already been reported as a bug internally. The documentation is wrong, this is not yet implemented.

Comment: As Ilian mentions, this is a documentation bug. An extension of `AssociationThread` is planned for the future, but this documentation should not have been in the product. Note that `AssociationThread` is not mentioned in the "what's new" page, guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn102.

Comment: @ilian Thank you for the quick feedbacks ;) I think it is much appreciated by the community !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is extracted from the comments to the question.

illian:

> It's already been reported as a bug internally. The documentation is wrong, this is not yet implemented

Stefan R.:

> As Ilian mentions, this is a documentation bug. An extension of `AssociationThread` is planned for the future, but this documentation should not have been in the product. Note that `AssociationThread` is not mentioned in the "what's new" page, guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn102